# Oracle sql query plan does not uses indices with or statement and a subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, query-planner

I have a query with 'or' statement and 'inner select' statement. When I check query plan it uses full table access and I don't know why this happens.

I created this test case to show my problem:

```
CREATE TABLE PERSON (
    ID                   NUMBER(18)           NOT NULL,
    NAME                 VARCHAR2(18)         NOT NULL,
    SURNAME              VARCHAR2(18)         NOT NULL
);

BEGIN
  FOR b IN 1..500000
  LOOP
     INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES (b,'name' || to_char(b),'surname' || to_char(b));
  END LOOP;
END;

CREATE INDEX PERSON_NAME_index ON PERSON(NAME);
CREATE INDEX PERSON_SURNAME_index ON PERSON(SURNAME);
```

And here is the problematic query:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM PERSON p
WHERE p.NAME = 'name300' or  p.SURNAME in (SELECT p2.SURNAME
                                       FROM PERSON p2
                                       WHERE p2.NAME = 'name500');
```

When I analyze the query plan, I saw that it uses full table access for person table. That slows my query time drastically and I dont know why this happens.

If I eliminate first constraint(p.NAME = 'name300') and query with only subselect statement, everthing works fine and query uses indices again.

Can someone explain me why query is not using my indices for the first case?

Comment: Did you gather statistics on the table?

Comment: Classic issue. Because of your OR the query plan doesn't manage to use the indexes and falls into a full table scan. Change your OR into an UNION like Gordon proposed below. Whenever you code an OR,  you should ALWAYS ask yourself if it can be replaced with a UNION.

Comment: @BobJarvis yes, I gathered statistics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OR` is difficult for databases to optimize.  You can split this into two queries and use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM PERSON p
WHERE p.NAME = 'name300'
UNION ALL
SELECT p.*
FROM PERSON p
WHERE p.NAME <> 'name300' AND
      p.SURNAME IN (SELECT p2.SURNAME
                    FROM PERSON p2
                    WHERE p2.NAME = 'name500'
                   );
```

Comment: One thought though :) why ALL in this case? The orginal query would not have returned dups.

Comment: @ThomasG . . . There is no reason to incur the overhead of removing duplicates, which would be the case if `UNION` were used.  This query doesn't return duplicates either, even if both conditions are true.

Comment: Can you give me more specific information about "or" optimization. A documentation would be great. Also, even oracle can translate query like you did(since its a simple logic transformation), i don't understand why it's not doing this.

Comment: @AlperenÜretmen . . . Query optimization is a very complex subject.  You should start with the documentation:  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25178_01/server.1111/e16638/optimops.htm.